# using profiles in iPython and Django

Tags: python, django, ipython

I've got a Django product I'm using iPython to interact with.

I'm trying to have modules automatically loaded when I start a shell:

python manage.py shell

I've copied .ipython/ipythonrc   to the root directory of the project and added to the file:

import_some module_name model1 model2

However, when I start the shell, these names are not being loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about ipythonrc, but if you only need the models, you could use [`django-extensions`](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/). After you install it, you've got a plethora of new managment commands, including `shell_plus`, which will open a ipython session and autoload all your models:

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

Answer (score 1):

BryanWheelock Your solution won't work because your shell is the result of the spawn not a direct interatction with it.  What you want to do is this - or at least this is what I do.

Within your workspace (the place where you type `python manage.py shell`) create a ipythonrc file. In it put the following:

```
include ~/.ipython/ipythonrc

execute from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# .
# .
# .
execute import_some module_name model1 model2
```

For example I also add the following lines in mine..

```
# Setup Logging
execute import sys
execute import logging
execute loglevel = logging.DEBUG
execute logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout )
execute log = logging.getLogger("")
execute log.setLevel(loglevel)
execute log.debug("Logging has been initialized from ipythonrc")
execute log.debug("Root Logger has been established - use \"log.LEVEL(MSG)\"")
execute log.setLevel(loglevel)
execute log.debug("log.setlevel(logging.DEBUG)")
execute print ""
```

This allows you to use logging in your modules and keep it DRY.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`shell_plus` command of django-extensions can import the model automatically, but it seems can not load the profile of ipython. I have did some hacky job to make this done.

use `start_ipython` to launch ipython shell instead of `embed` and pass some arguments to it.

I have also wrote a blog post, you can find the detail [here](http://blog.michaelyin.info/2015/04/05/using-profiles-in-ipython-and-django/)